# user registration and authenation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am having issues trying to registering user using my RegisterController that I modified from a blog;

```
protected function register(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var User $user */
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'accno'    => 'required|string|max:20',
            'acc_type' => 'required|string|max:10',
            'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
        try {
            $validatedData['password']        = bcrypt(\Arr::get($validatedData, 'password'));
            $validatedData['activation_code'] = str::random(30).time();
            $user                             = app(User::class)->create($validatedData);
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            logger()->error($exception);

            return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Unable to create new user.');
        }
        $user->notify(new UserRegisteredSuccessfully($user));

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Successfully created a new account. Please check your email and activate your account.');

    }
```

all the codes seem fine and I correctly add the mysql database to .env file but when I try creating a user, I get the 'Unable to create new user' error.
please I need help knowing where I went wrong.

the expectation log I'm getting is

````
  #sql: "insert into `users` (`accno`, `acc_type`, `name`, `email`, `password`, `activation_code`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
  #bindings: array:8 [▶]
  #message: "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'username' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`accno`, `acc_type`, `name`, `email`, `password`,  ▶"
  #code: "HY000"
  #file: "C:\Users\user pc\Documents\website\SAB\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php"
  #line: 669
  -previous: PDOException {#294 ▶}
  +errorInfo: array:3 [▶]
  trace: {▶}
}```
````

Comment: And what exception does your logs show?

Comment: Validating `name` twice?

Comment: @kerbholz I deleted that initially that wasn't the problem

Comment: @JeremyHarris it shows this

Comment: I solved the issue after looking carefully at the exception logs thanks